# VBA Excel Function for returning file size in byte

Tags: vba, excel, function, size, byte

I wish to return the file size of some files in the same folder or in a different one with VBA in Excel 2010.

Comment: sorry my mistake, the function works perfectly. My computer is in german language settings that's why i needed to use ";" not ","
Thanks anyway

Comment: Instead of `If Right(strFolder, 1) <> "\" Then strFolder = strFolder & "\"` and then `strFolder & strFile` just use `OFS.BuildPath(strFolder, strFile)`.

Comment: Please edit the question to reflect your new insight, post an answer, or delete it... Right now it just sits there unanswered, potentially wasting everyone's time.

Comment: @Floris yes you are right, but the answer that i posted is correct, should i post the same answer again? If someone reads the comments(everybody does) they will see it at that moment.

Comment: The point of posting an answer is that people don't say "oh look, nobody has been able to answer that one, I will go and take a look!" And after reading the question and the comments, they realize no help was needed... But they won't get their five minutes back. So - thanks for posting your solution!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here how to use it in Excel Cell:

```
 =GetDirOrFileSize("C:\Users\xxx\Playground\","filename.xxx")
```

If you have a german Windows than:

```
=GetDirOrFileSize("C:\Users\xxx\Playground\";"filename.xxx")
```

Here is the function for the VBA modul: (Just enable the Developer tools, and copy and paste this into a new modul)

```
Function GetDirOrFileSize(strFolder As String, Optional strFile As Variant) As Long

'Call Sequence: GetDirOrFileSize("drive\path"[,"filename.ext"])

   Dim lngFSize As Long, lngDSize As Long
   Dim oFO As Object
   Dim oFD As Object
   Dim OFS As Object

   lngFSize = 0
   Set OFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

   If strFolder = "" Then strFolder = ActiveWorkbook.path
   If Right(strFolder, 1) <> "\" Then strFolder = strFolder & "\"
   'Thanks to Jean-Francois Corbett, you can use also OFS.BuildPath(strFolder, strFile)

   If OFS.FolderExists(strFolder) Then
     If Not IsMissing(strFile) Then

       If OFS.FileExists(strFolder & strFile) Then
         Set oFO = OFS.Getfile(strFolder & strFile)
         GetDirOrFileSize = oFO.Size
       End If

       Else
        Set oFD = OFS.GetFolder(strFolder)
        GetDirOrFileSize = oFD.Size
       End If

   End If

End Function   '*** GetDirOrFileSize ***
```

Comment: This is very strange! What do you think the `;` is doing? Is it separating the two parameters of your function, or is it acting as a concatenate operator? I have never seen it used as the former, and only in `Print` statements as the latter. In your function, does the `IsMissing (StrFile)` return True or False? Is the semicolon also used if you call the function from within VBA, or only if it is a spreadsheet function?

Comment: `;` is a language setting option in Windows, you can change it everytime. In German settings the `,` is not working in excel as a separator. It is under Settings, Regions and Language as Format German.

Comment: German and most of other European Excells, they all use ;. As well as translations of function names. Stupid, but true.

Answer (score 31):

There is a very nice and simple VBA function, which was not mentioned so far, [FileLen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/filelen-function):

`FileLen("C:\Temp\test file.xls")`

It returns the size of the file in **bytes**.

In combination with looping through files in a directory it's possible to achieve what you originally wanted (get sizes of files in a folder).

Comment: Unfortunately it only works for <2GB files unless you use some special math, then it is restricted to <4GB.