# Fetch size of file in excel

Tags: excel, vba

For example:

```
Cell A                           | Cell B   
==================================
http://m---.com/myfile.txt       |   4kbs
--------------------------------------------
http://m---.com/myfile.txt       |   10kbs
--------------------------------------------
http://m---.com/myfile.doc       |  104kbs
----------------------------------------------
http://m---.com/myfile.jpg       |   102kbs
```

I just have URL lists in Cell A and I want to have file size in Cell B.

I tried VBA code for this but its not working. One thing more, I just got this code from internet and its not mine, but it was not help me. Here is code:

```
print file path Cells(i + 1, 1) = objFile.Path 'print size Cells(i + 1, 2) = objFile.Size
```

Is it possible to fetch the file size on a particular URL in excel? Check the above example, I have the URLs in column A and want to fetch the file size in Column B.

Comment: Have you tried `FileLen()`? It should return the file size in bytes..

Comment: thanks for suggestion , no i dont  know much about this .. let me search in google and will let you know if got something .. thanks

Comment: @Tyeler thanks i found this on net "For example:

Dim LResult As Long

LResult = FileLen("C:\instructions.doc")"  but i think it will not work for me, as i have lot of urls in Cell A . and im not able to put this lot of data one by one in FileLen (filepath) . hope their is any formula or code that will pick values from Cell A and provide result (File Size) in Cell B.

Comment: What about sending a request for headers only by Microsoft.XMLHHTP and then getting "Content-Length"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA Excel Function for returning file size in byte](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15883237/vba-excel-function-for-returning-file-size-in-byte)

Comment: @BruceWayne in that question user need data from local folder , in my from url .. thanks

Comment: @Tyeler can you explain it more . getting content-length may not work becuse some of files are .jpg i mean images. if it work for this type of file then can you please tell more about it .. thanks for your time

Comment: @Tyeler  i found this code online   Use xmlhttp and a "HEAD" request. Part of the response is the file size.

'***********************************************
` Sub Tester()
Msgbox FileSize("site.com/i/head.jpg")
End Sub

Function FileSize(sURL As String)
Dim oXHTTP As Object
Set oXHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
oXHTTP.Open "HEAD", sURL, False
oXHTTP.send
If oXHTTP.Status = 200 Then
FileSize = oXHTTP.getResponseHeader("Content-Length")
Else
FileSize = -1
End If
End Function`  but how to put Cell A Values automatic so no need to put url for every time .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my further explanation for the comment I made:

```
Function URLFileSize(urlLink As String) As String
    Dim xmlObj As Object
    Set xmlObj = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

    xmlObj.Open "HEAD", urlLink, False
    xmlObj.Send
    If xmlObj.Status = 200 Then
        URLFileSize = xmlObj.getResponseHeader("Content-Length")
    Else: URLFileSize = -1
    End If

    Set xmlObj = Nothing
End Function
```

To use this function in a cell, in cell B2 put `=URLFileSize(A2)` and it will display the bytes in cell B2.

To use in VBA, call on it like any other function: `RandomVariable = URLFileSize(fullUrlString)`

Comment: thanks , can you please tell me how i run this code because in excel vba i think use sub to start and end function . and one more thing as i have lot of urls in Cell A so it will pick one by one automatic or every time i need to put one url in code and then run code .. thanks for sharing your knowledge

Comment: I'm glad I could help!